# Box API: Get_managed_users returning all users

Tags: box-api

Using the Box 1.0 REST API, I am trying to work with the functions in SOAP UI.

The API doc for get_managed_users with user_id=12345 (internal id retrieved with get_user_id call correctly) is returning all the users.   The docs say that would be the case if you do not specify a user_id value.  But my full command is: (Token and API key changed to protect the clueless)

```
https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?user_id=27360&auth_token=blahbalhblah1234&action=get_managed_users&api_key=someKeyYouShouldNotSee
```

Now I could work with the complete result list, but that won't scale as we get thousands of users into the system.

I can make a call with edit_managed_user, using the same user_id value and the change is reflected in the UI, and in the next get_managed_users call.  Thus I do have the correct user_id value, I would so assume.

I tried testuser@gmail.com as the user_id value as well, and get the entire list back.  This leads me to believe that somehow I am sending user_id wrong, but I just do not see it.

Any hints?  Why, with what seems like a valid user_id value is it acting like it is absent or incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have either called this method with an invalid user_id, or one that is not in your set of managed users.  Can you double check that the user comes back in your list of already managed users?

Comment: Yes I get the requested user, with the correct number in the response.  And I made it as my co-admin account in the Box UI to test.  And I can modify it as I noted above which proves I have it correct.